# Show that the set $A := \{x \in Q : x < 0 \text{ or } x^{2} < 2\}$ has no maximum. Does it have a supremum? If yes, what is it?

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the set
$$A := \{x \in Q : x < 0  \text{ or }  x^{2} < 2\}$$

has no maximum. Does it have a supremum? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Since There is always some rational point as much as you want near to every number, in your question, $-\sqrt 2 \ \& \  0$, from both sides, So there is neither minimum nor maximum, respectively. But these number are infimum and supremum, respectively. Can you prove it now? Tell me how much you can continue from this hint...